# Python Selenium unable to locate element even thought it shows up in inspect tab

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I run a query to a webpage and selenium opens the page and I wait till all the scripts are loaded. Then I perform a tag search and by far I've tried every method but it always returns 
`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".dowload"}`

even though that element is visible on the page and shows up on the inspect tab.

Here's the code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions
from time import sleep

options = ChromeOptions()
# options.addargument("--headless=new")
driver = Chrome(options=options)
driver.set_page_load_timeout(10.0)
Sike = "https://www.instagram.com/"
downloadLink = 'https://gotaku1.com/download?id=OTA3OTk=&typesub=Gogoanime-DUB&title=Death+Note+%28Dub%29+Episode+1'

driver.get(Sike)
sleep(5)
driver.execute_script(f'''window.open("{downloadLink}","_blank");''')
driver.execute_script(f'''window.open("{downloadLink}","_blank");''')
driver.execute_script(f'''window.open("{downloadLink}","_blank");''')
sleep(10)
tags = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'dowload')
print(tags)
```

The instagram link is just there for no reason

Comment: can you share the HTML part if possible.

Comment: How do I do that? When I try to download it the scripts dont load

Comment: Then how did you find this class name?tags = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'dowload')

Comment: By using inspect element as I mentioned above

Comment: Is that class name spelled correctly?  You're sure it's `dowload`, and not `download`?

Comment: Yepp its quite wierd but thats exactly whats its named

Comment: I can see {.dowload} css is returning 9 elements on that page. you can use find_elements method to get all the download tags.

Comment: Yes thats what i was doing initially but when it stopped working I just used a single tag but thats not the point. It doesnt return any of those elements

Comment: driver.get(downloadLink);  tags = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'dowload')
print(tags)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are opening multiple (3) tabs, but Selenium is trying to find the element on the first opened tab (instagram.com)

Comment: I thought selenium worked on the active tab. How do I get it to work on the active tab instead of other opened ones

Comment: You can try this to switch to the last opened tab -
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1]), but I recommend you to operate in one tab